# WPF Popup closing unexpectedly

Tags: c#, wpf, popup

I have an application with a TextBox. Whenever the TextBox is clicked by the user a Popup should appear offering additional options. I managed to do this using the XAML code below. However the Popup automatically closes when I click the CheckBox. How can this be prevented?

I also tried binding the IsOpen property of the Pupup to my view model and setting it to true with the LeftClick MouseAction of the TextBox but then the TextBox looses focus and the actual input gets very fiddly.

The current XAML code:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfPopupTest.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="800">
    <Grid>
        <TextBox x:Name="Input" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Width="200" />
        <Popup PlacementTarget="{Binding ElementName=Input}" Placement="Top">
            <Popup.Style>
                <Style TargetType="{x:Type Popup}">
                    <Style.Triggers>
                        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ElementName=Input, Path=IsFocused}" Value="True">
                            <Setter  Property="IsOpen" Value="True" />
                        </DataTrigger>
                    </Style.Triggers>
                </Style>
            </Popup.Style>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                <CheckBox/>
                <TextBlock Grid.Column="1">Option</TextBlock>
            </StackPanel>
        </Popup>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Comment: i'm assuming that the focus of the pop up itself shifts to the checkbox and the pop up closes as per the data trigger binding.Tricky one to sort out.

Answer (score -1):

As Digitalsa1nt suggested, the problem is that the textbox loses focus when you click the CheckBox, and the trigger stops keeping the popup open.

But if the CheckBox never gets focused, this is not an issue.

```
<CheckBox Focusable="False"/>
```